# jar file trouble to have path to file inside jar

Tags: jar, sbt

I have a .jar file, compiled with the help of the sbt assembly. The program that the sbt builds, inside has a reference to a file with a direct path indication - src/bla/bla.txt. When I run a jar file not from the project's directory, the program can not find the file bla.txt on the specified path. How to correctly specify the path to the file so that the program can have access

Comment: Please, add relevant code to your question: in particular how do you refer to that file in your code

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is to put the bla.txt to
src/main/resources/  -folder 
and then you can read it using Source.

```
import scala.io.Source
```

**scala 2.12**

```
val blaLines = Source.fromResource("bla.txt").getLines
```

**scala 2.11**

```
val blaLines = Source.fromInputStream( getClass.getResourceAsStream("/bla.txt") ).getLines
```

Comment: Yes, I put it into resources, and I do smthng like this 
    **Source.fromFile(getClass.getResource("/languages/english/words.txt").getPath).getLines.toArray** 
But it's also throw exception, that no such file or directory

Comment: Important remark that if I start this code into IDE, it'll be ok, but if I Start it like .jar in the random rep, ill throw exception

Comment: Hey, the file paths are tricky when reading files from resources as they get moved when packaged. Did you try like I said with using input streams?